# Queue using a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Can someone explain the delete function below? It is supposed to delete an element from the queue and I left a comment on the line where I start being confused. I understand that we need to delete the last element, but I don't see how they are setting the second last element to NULL.

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *link;
} NODE;

NODE *front, *rear; // global declarations
front = rear = NULL;

int Delete() {
  int info;
  NODE *todelete;

  if (front == NULL) {
    printf(" Underflow!!!");
    return -1;
  } else {
    todelelete = front;
    //info = front->data; // I don't get it from here

    if (front == rear)
      rear = NULL;
    front = front->link;
    todelete->link = NULL;
    free(todelte);
    //return(info);
  }
}
```

Comment: This cannot be the complete code. Once you write the complete code, you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
info=front->data;
```

stores the data of the list's head just to return it later; it isthe data to be dequeued. Then, the special case where `todelete` is the only node in the list is handled. Next, the `front` pointer is moved to the originally second node of the queue. Finaly, `todelete` is freed. Strictly speaking, the line

```
todelete->link=NULL
```

is not necessary, but it clarifies the process of dequeuing the element completely before deleting it.

Comment: I thought front pointer is the first element in the queue. So I thought if front->link points to the next element but there is none? Could you help me clarify it. Ps thanks very much for your reply

Comment: As I understand it, if there is exactly one element in the list, `front->link` will be `NULL`. If there is more than one element in the list, `front->link` will point to the second element.

Comment: Waht you seem to be explaining is stacks. In queues to delete the first element in the queue so effectively you want access to the second last element to point to NULL and I dont see how this is doing it

Comment: By setting `front=front->next` the second element is made the first; afterwards the originally first element is removed, as `todelete` points to it.

Comment: Sorry Codor, I solved it the link is to the previous element, I was just after implementing this using stacks so I thought it was the next element.

Comment: You're welcome. Things can be a fiddle, especially if part of some larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply rename "link" to "next" it becomes much clearer.
Basically you keep a bookmark on what element you want to remove, then you connect the elements of the queue skipping that element, then you delete the element that you bookmarked. That's because otherwise you get a memory leak.
For example, if you have a list that has:

```
[1]->[2]->[3]->[4]
```

and you want to remove element [2], what you do is keep a bookmark on [2], let's say x:[2], then you make it so that the "next" from [1] is [3], which gives you

```
[1]->[3]->[4]
```

then you delete x:[2].